# more than one condition in for each loop in xsl file

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new here so if i make some mistakes please don't be too angry on me.S o i have small snippet of code in xml and one xsl file that should make a small table from my xml file.but i have more than one condition in my for each loop and what is even more interesting those two condition are not part of the same level of nodes or "parents" one is on higher level in hierarchy and on is on lower level so could you please help me with that. Here is the code for xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="DZ07.xsl"?>
<students>
         <student>
                 <name> John </name>
                 <surname> Piterson </surname>
                 <age> 21 </age>
                 <exam>
                         <subject>
                                  <grade> 5 </grade>
                                  <code> IT210 </code>
                         </subject>
                         <subject>
                                  <grade> 7 </grade>
                                  <code> IT101 </code>
                         </subject>
                </exam>
       </student>
       <student>
               <name> Peter </name>
               <surname> Max </surname>
               <age> 26 </age>
               <exam>
                       <subject>
                                <grade> 9 </grade>
                                <code> IT210 </code>
                       </subject>
                       <subject>
                                <grade> 10 </grade>
                                <code> IT101 </code>
                       </subject>
              </exam>
    </student>
</students>
```

and xsl code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Students that passed the exam:</h2>
<table border="1">
<tr bgcolor="red">
   <th align="left">Name</th>
   <th align="left">Surname</th>
   <th align="left">Age</th>
   <th align="left">Grade</th>
   <th align="left">Code</th>
</tr>
<xsl:for-each select="students/student[age>=22 or 
 students/student/exam/subject[grade>=6 and code=' IT210 ']]">
<tr bgcolor="yellow">
 <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
 <td><xsl:value-of select="surname"/></td>
 <td><xsl:value-of select="age"/></td>
 <td><xsl:value-of select="grade"/></td>
 <td><xsl:value-of select="code"/></td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please specify exactly in what way exactly you'd like us to help? Are you struggling with syntax, logic, etc... ? Mention it in the question.

Comment: With syntax this what i wrote for each loop obviously is not working when i start xml in firefox so could anyone help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
<xsl:for-each select="students/student[age>=22 or exam/subject[grade>=7 and code=' IT210 ']]">
<tr bgcolor="yellow">
 <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
 <td><xsl:value-of select="surname"/></td>
 <td><xsl:value-of select="age"/></td>
 <td><xsl:value-of select="exam/subject/grade"/></td>
 <td><xsl:value-of select="exam/subject/code"/></td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: still not working, but thanks for help,i  will keep looking in this direction

Comment: ah my mistake :) i forgot one letter :) thanks man.i accept your answer